# Issue with Fill-Height property when content on page changes

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I've been searching around for answers to this question, but couldn't find a way to formulate the question in an accurate way. The issue is as follows:

I've created a Login page which contains a `v-card` in the center of the page (horizontally and vertically centered). I centered it vertically using the fill-height property. Simplified code:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid fill-height @keyup.enter="login">
    <v-row class="justify-center" no-gutters>
      <v-col cols="12" md="3">
        <v-card outlined elevation="10">
          <v-card-title class="display-1 amber--text text--lighten-1">Login</v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-form v-model="valid" ref="form">
              <v-container>
                <v-row class="justify-center">
                  <v-col cols="12" md="12">
                    <v-text-field
                      label="E-mail address"
                      v-model="email"
                      autocomplete="off"
                      required
                      dense
                      outlined
                      hide-details
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-btn block @click="login" class="my-2 primary grey--text text--darken-4">Login</v-btn>
              </v-container>
            </v-form>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

In my App.vue I have the following code:

```
  <v-app id="inspire" :style="{background: $vuetify.theme.themes.dark.background}">
    <Header></Header>
    <v-content>
      <v-alert class="mb-0" v-if="alert && alert.message" transition="scroll-y-transition" :type="`${alert.type}`" >{{alert.message}}</v-alert>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
    <Footer class="hidden-sm-and-down"></Footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

The alert is triggered by Vuex; in case an endpoint (in this case the login endpoint) gives back an error, a new alert is created and is shown on the page. This all works fine, except for the lay-out on my Login page. When an alert is created, the Login content no longer fits on the page and the content goes outside of the dark background. It's a bit hard to see but for clarification I added this screenshot:

[image]

What would be the most clean way to solve this issue? I already tried adding margins/padding to the bottom of the v-card, but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Jeroen

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Not really a direct solution but you might look into vuetify-banners which are pretty much the type of container you want https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/banners#banners